# Binding DataGridColumns with multiple ObservableCollections List (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a problem and trying to solve by searching did not succeed. So I try it here with specific help:
I have a MainWindow Application with different Tabs. One Tab should have a DataGrid with 4 columns. I want to fill them with a List of objects.
My implementation in MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
// 4 times this kind of Code
private ObservableCollection<bool> _StatusBitsSimulateActiveList = null;
private ObservableCollection<string> _StatusBitsNameList = null;
private ObservableCollection<bool> _ActualStatusBitsList = null;
private ObservableCollection<bool> _SimulatedStatusBitsList = null;

public ObservableCollection<bool> StatusBitsSimulateActiveList
{
   get
   {
       List<bool> list = Manager._StatusBits.GetSimulatedStatusBitsList();
       _StatusBitsSimulateActiveList = new ObservableCollection<bool>(list);
        return _StatusBitsSimulateActiveList;
   }
   set
   {
        _StatusBitsSimulateActiveList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
   }
}
```

The MainWindow.xaml file contains:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="SimulatedBitsDataGrid" MinRowHeight="25" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    Margin="5" AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue" AlternationCount="2" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding StatusBitsSimulateActiveList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Simulation Active"/>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" Header="Status Bits Name">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock.Text>
                                                <Binding Mode="TwoWay" Path="StatusBitsNameList"></Binding>
                                            </TextBlock.Text>
                                        </TextBlock>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding ActualStatusBitsList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Status Bit SPS"/>
                            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding SimulatedStatusBitsList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Simulated Value"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I have a class, where the Data is stored and retrieved (see Manager._StatusBits) with some methods to get and set data.
The DataGrid is not filling with data. can someone help?

I tried through ItemsSource="Binding" and then Binding to the Lists. Not working.
Looked through the internet and found no solution, maybe I do not understand the mechanics. I am quite new to wpf, only worked on C++ and mfc.

***Edit:***
So I tried some of the answers and now understand a little bit more. But one issue I cannot resolve. I do not tried with those kinds of ViewModels (maybe this could help, won't try now).
Here is my code, which is working oneWay, but not TwoWay, because no GUI interaction with the Grid is noticed. What is Missing?
Notice, this code was partly written from someone else, I trying to resolve some issues and add some features:

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
InitializeComponent();
this.DataContext = this; // Why do someone need to do this? Because of relativeSource Binding? see .xaml file
StatusBitDataGrid.DataContext = Manager._StatusBits.dataList; // there is a manager, which manages the objects, the Manager is created in the MainWindow
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="APP.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="EFEM-Client Plus+" Height="900" Width="1200"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Closing="OnWindowClosing"
        x:Name="window1"
        >
<DataGrid x:Name="StatusBitDataGrid" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding}" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn CanUserSort="False" Binding="{Binding SimulateActive, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Simulation Active"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" Header="Status Bits Name" CanUserSort="False">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock.Text>
                            <Binding Mode="TwoWay" Path="StatusBitsName"></Binding>
                        </TextBlock.Text>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding ActualBitValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Status Bit SPS" CanUserSort="False" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding SimulatedBitValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Simulated Value" CanUserSort="False"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

StatusBits.cs

```
public class StatusBits {
[...]
public StatusBits()
{
   [...]
   PopulateObservable();
}
[...]
private ObservableCollection<StatusBitsSingleData> _dataList = new ObservableCollection<StatusBitsSingleData>();

        public ObservableCollection<StatusBitsSingleData> dataList
        {
            get { return _dataList; }
            set { _dataList = value; } // Code and Style never enters the setter...
        }
private void PopulateObservable()
        {
            dataList.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < maxSemDexStatus; i++)
            {
                dataList.Add(new StatusBitsSingleData(StatusBitsSimulateActive[i], StatusBitsName[i], ActualStatusBits[i], SimulatedStatusBits[i]));
            }
        }
[...]
// The SingleData Class, here the setter is used by the program
public class StatusBitsSingleData
{
    public bool SimulateActive { get; set; }
    public string StatusBitsName { get; set; }
    public bool ActualBitValue { get; set; }
    public bool SimulatedBitValue { get; set; }
    public StatusBitsSingleData(bool simA, string name, bool actu, bool sim)
    {
        SimulateActive = simA; StatusBitsName = name; ActualBitValue = actu; SimulatedBitValue = sim;
    }
}
}
```

Because the setter is used in public class StatusBitsSingleData, I tried to make a custom Notifier, but failed ...

Comment: Welcome to the forum. I think that you will need to create a composite class so that each column is one property in the class, create an ObservableCollection of that class (it becomes the data source) then each column is bound to an indivdual property of that class.

Comment: I would also recommend that you don't populate your ObservableCollection within its getter, but instead perform that elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, so i construct it like:
`public class DataCollection : INotifyPropertyChanged { ObservableCollection<bool>_StatusBitsSimulateActiveList {get; set;} ...}` then bind the class into the DataGrid with `<Datagrid ItemsSource="DataCollection">` and each column with `DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding _StatusBitsSimulateActiveList }"`?

Comment: No. Itemssource should be bound to one collection of rowviewmodel. 
exposed by a public property on your window's viewmodel. Rowviewmodel should have a property per column.  Three bool properties and one string property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues that need stating.

- A `DataGrid` can only be bound to one `ObservableCollection`.
- A `DataGrid.Column` is bound to a single property of the class
  type contained within the `ObservableCollection`
- An `ObservableCollection` implements the `INotifyProperty` interface and so does not require further code support when bound.

I'm not sure what you're attempting to do with your code but on the first point I would amalgamate all of the data that you wish to show within a `DataGrid.Row` into a single class type and have a view model that includes an `ObservableCollection` of that type e.g.

```
public class StatusBitClass 
{
    public bool SimulatedActive { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool ActualStatus { get; set; }
    public bool SimulatedStatus { get; set; }
}
```

I don't recommend using the getter for an `ObservableCollection` to populate its data source, instead populate it with a ViewMode function, here I use a `RelayCommand` (an `ICommand` implementation), but you may link into some automated data source e.g., web API or database.

So, here's a suitable ViewModel - note that `IStatusBitsDataViewModel` is an interface type that just defines the public parts of the `StatusBitsDataViewModel`. I've not included it, but I'll explain why I use a defined interface later.

```
public class StatusBitsDataViewModel:IStatusBitsDataViewModel
{
    public StatusBitsDataViewModel()
    {
        PopulateListCommand = new RelayCommand(PopulateListData);
        StatusBitClasses = new ObservableCollection<StatusBitClass>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<StatusBitClass> StatusBitClasses { get; set; }

    public RelayCommand PopulateListCommand { get; }

    //This function populates the ObservableCollection with test data
    // replace it with one that uses your real data source
    private void PopulateListData(object o)
    {
        var data = new List<StatusBitClass>()
        {
            new StatusBitClass(){ActualStatus = false, Name = "Status 1", SimulatedActive = false, SimulatedStatus = false},
            new StatusBitClass(){ActualStatus = true, Name = "Status 2", SimulatedActive = false, SimulatedStatus = true},
            new StatusBitClass(){ActualStatus = false, Name = "Status 3", SimulatedActive = true, SimulatedStatus = false},
            new StatusBitClass(){ActualStatus = true, Name = "Status 4", SimulatedActive = false, SimulatedStatus = true},
            new StatusBitClass(){ActualStatus = false, Name = "Status 5", SimulatedActive = true, SimulatedStatus = false},
            new StatusBitClass(){ActualStatus = true, Name = "Status 6", SimulatedActive = false, SimulatedStatus = true},
            new StatusBitClass(){ActualStatus = false, Name = "Status 7", SimulatedActive = true, SimulatedStatus = false},
        };
        foreach (var entry in data)
        {
            StatusBitClasses.Add(entry);
        }
    }

}
```

Now, your View will require a `DataContext` setting to the ViewModel, this I tend to do in the Views code behind file e.g., the `.cs` file associated with it, if only because I can use dependency injection and pass a concrete type into it, and thus change the behaviour at run time e.g., switch between using a ViewModel that uses a real data source or one that uses predefined test data, say for unit testing.

So, the Code behind is:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for StatusDataWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class StatusDataWindow : Window
{
    public StatusDataWindow(IStatusBitsDataViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new StatusBitsDataViewModel(); //forcing to use concrete type
    }
}
```

Here's the XAML for an example window that demonstrates data binding and how to trigger the population of a `DataGrid` with data from the UI.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.StatusDataWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="StatusDataWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="200"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="0"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding StatusBitClasses}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Name }"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Simulated Active" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding SimulatedActive }"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Actual Status" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding ActualStatus }"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Simulated Status" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding SimulatedStatus }"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Fill" Width="40" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="40"  Command="{Binding PopulateListCommand}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I hope that this helps.

**Edit**
As you're now asking about changing data within the `DataGrid` and passing that back then you need to make a slight change so that the action of changing the data actually triggers the data change in the bound class.

Let us change the data column class so that the section now reads:

```
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay }"/>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Simulated Active" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding SimulatedActive, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }"/>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Actual Status" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding ActualStatus, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }"/>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Simulated Status" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding SimulatedStatus, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

It's easier to display and change a check box value when using Booleans than changing text.

Specifying when the update event to the bound property should be triggered is the key here.
(Hint place a breakpoint on `StatusBitClass` property setter to prove it works).

If you are wanting to change `StatusBitClass` property values programmatically and have them update within the `DataGrid` then you'll need to ensure that those properties support `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

You could create a separate ViewModel class or just have `StatusBitClass` implement `INotifyPripertyChanged`.

```
public class StatusBitClass: INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    private bool _simulatedActive;
    private bool _actualStatus;
    private bool _simulatedStatus;

    public bool SimulatedActive 
    { 
        get =>_simulatedActive;
        set => SetField(ref _simulatedActive, value);
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool ActualStatus
    {
        get => _actualStatus;
        set => SetField(ref _actualStatus, value);
    }

    public bool SimulatedStatus
    {
        get => _simulatedStatus;
        set => SetField(ref _simulatedStatus, value);
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now if you change a `StatusBitClass` property value after it has been added to the `ObservableCollection` you'll see the value update within the `DataGrid`, without it you would need to force a refresh of the window by some other means.

Comment: Thank you very much, please look into my edit on Top. This is working now one way, but not two way

Comment: Ok, so in addition you wish to change the status bit values from the UI. I'll update my code.

Comment: I hope that the above answers your questions. If so, then please mark it so.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I have a basic misunderstanding of the problem with wpf. So I tried a basic project which reflects the top problem:
MainWindow.xaml contains

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_DataGrid_Binding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="DataGridObject" AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue" AlternationCount="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                  >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn CanUserSort="False" Binding="{Binding _StatusBitsSimulateActive, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Simulation Active" />
                <DataGridTextColumn CanUserSort="False" Binding="{Binding _StatusBitsName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Name" />
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn CanUserSort="False" Binding="{Binding _ActualStatusBits, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Actual" />
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn CanUserSort="False" Binding="{Binding _SimulatedStatusBits, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Simulation" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Data.cs contains:

```
public class Data : INotifyCollectionChanged
    {
        public List<bool> StatusBitsSimulateActive = new List<bool>();
        public List<string> StatusBitsName = new List<string>();
        public List<bool> ActualStatusBits = new List<bool>();
        public List<bool> SimulatedStatusBits = new List<bool>();

        public Data()
        {
            PopulateLists();
        }

        event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged
        {
            add
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            remove
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        private void PopulateLists()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (rnd.Next(10) < 5)
                {
                    StatusBitsSimulateActive.Add(true);
                    StatusBitsName.Add("LOL");
                    ActualStatusBits.Add(false);
                    SimulatedStatusBits.Add(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    StatusBitsSimulateActive.Add(false);
                    StatusBitsName.Add("NotFunny");
                    ActualStatusBits.Add(true);
                    SimulatedStatusBits.Add(false);
                }
            }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<bool> _StatusBitsSimulateActive
        {
            get
            {
                ObservableCollection<bool> result = new ObservableCollection<bool>(StatusBitsSimulateActive);
                return result;
            }
            set
            {
                _StatusBitsSimulateActive = value;
            }
        }
        [...] 3 times
    }
```

This does not work. The Lists are populated, but the Binding is not working. What is missing here?